# TCP messages over ISO TCP/RFC 1006

Tags: spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration, rfc

I have a Spring Integration project configured via annotations with the following configuration related to TCP:

```
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpIn(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter receiver = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    receiver.setOutputChannel(fromTcpReceiver());
    receiver.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return receiver;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    factory.setSoKeepAlive(keepAlive);
    factory.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOut(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {     
    TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    sender.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return sender;
}
```

In Spring Integration, what is the best way to encapsulate TCP messages over ISO TCP/RFC 1006 ?

Basically, TCP ISO adds a step to the initial connection but also an additional header to each sent/received TCP message.

I was reading the documentation but I do not know what could be the best way to this type of message enrichment and negotiation. Is this possible with Spring Integration?

I have 3 ideas:

- messageBuilderFactory
- Serializer/Deserializer
- TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain

Any help/example is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the RFC but you will likely need a combination of custom serializer/deserializer, as well as a custom `TcpMessageMapper` to map the header(s) to/from Spring Integration message header(s).

Take a look at the [MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper.java) for an example.

Comment: Finally, I a using a custom @Transformer. This is because of initiation process